I have tried to remove the page numbering of QPrintPreviewWidget, but now it is not dispalying the content
I have tried to remove the page numbering in my page preview, but it when I tried to set the page size to the document it does not display the content to visualize. If someone can help me to determinate if is possible create a widget that the user the hit when they desire to numbering or not the pages.

The code is the following
def auto_num_checked(self):
    value = self.auto_check_box.checkState()
    self.auto_check_box.setChecked(value)


def prin_preview(self):
    """
    This funciton create a window that allows to the customer customize his page size
    :return: QPrinter
    """
    self.preview_page_dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
    self.preview_page_dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Icons/Main_logo.png"))
    self.preview_page_dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.prepare_the_document_to_visualize)
    self.preview_page_dialog.exec_()


def prepare_the_document_to_visualize(self,printer: QPrinter):
    self.printer = printer
    self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
    self.document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
    self.printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.Letter))
    self.document.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(self.printer.width(), self.printer.height()))
    self.document.print_(self.printer)


def print_document(self):

    self.printer = QPrinter()

    dialog_printer = QPrintDialog(self.printer)
    if dialog_printer.exec_():

        self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
        self.document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
        self.document.print_(self.printer)`

Reeive an answer that can resolve my issue
Minimal Reproducible Example
import sys

""""
PyQT Version: PyQt 5
Operative system: Windows 11
IDE 
-------
PyCharm 2023.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-233.15026.15, built on March 21, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1087.23 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4062M
Cores: 16
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.jetbrains.space (233.15026.16)

------



"""
import setuptools
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QTextEdit, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import  QPrintPreviewDialog, QPrinter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSizeF
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QPageSize

class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit :QTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self) # Creating Text Edit widget
        self.preview_button= QPushButton(self, text ="&Preview Button") # Creating Button To display the vizualization
        self.printer: QPrinter = QPrinter() # Object QPinter this object is used to set the Print Support Object

        self.preview_button.clicked.connect(self.preview_clicked) # Connecting the clicked signal to the function that will display the dialog box

        # Configuring the widget possition and geometry
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(10,10, 100,30)
        self.preview_button.setGeometry(10,50, 100,30)

    def preview_clicked(self):
        dialog_privew = QPrintPreviewDialog() # Creating the Printer Preview Dialog Box
        dialog_privew.paintRequested.connect(self.display_paint_view) # Connecting the Signal to obtain the printer
        dialog_privew.exec_() # displaying the widget

    def display_paint_view(self,printer):
        self.printer : QPrinter= printer # Asigning the printer object that comes from the dialog_privew
        self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - ") # Setting the Doc name to print
        document = self.text_edit.document() # Getting the Document to print
        document.setPageSize(QSizeF(0,0)) # Change the number grather than 0 and you obtain a blank page
        document.print_(self.printer) # Getting the layout to vizualize the document.


    # This code allows to visualize the content on the text edit with the page enumerated


I don't understand the relation between removing page numbering and setting the page size. Also, how are you removing the page numbers? Your code doesn't seem to show that. Please provide a proper [mre].

This par that you say
" I don't understand the relation between removing page numbering and setting the page size. Also, how are you removing the page numbers? Your code doesn't seem to show that. Please provide a proper minimal reproducible example." , is for this documetation
https://forum.qt.io/topic/14370/solved-page-number-in-qtextdocument-for-envelopes/2

Why are you setting the document size to (1, 1)? That doesn't make any sense. If you're referring to the qt forum post above, it clearly says that the page number is shown when the page size is not valid. Making the page size valid means that you need to set an appropriate page size, not a random (and pointless) one such as 1, 1. Just set the page size to the printer's width() and height().

The number on the bottom of the page is still there, I would like to remove the number and perverse the content, I use 1,1, to test and verify what scalation is acceptable for the widget, your solution does not remove the autonumbering I am near to think that it is not possible to hide or show this specific parameter.

That assumption is only based on partial attempts, thus pointless. Using 1, 1 makes no sense, as it will clip page contents to one pixel (so, for obvious reasons, no content will be shown at all). Besides, that size doesn't affect the preview widget, so, again, it's pointless. The most important issue you have is doing the wrong thing, which results in not showing the document contents, so provide a proper MRE that does show the contents of the document but still shows page numbers even if you believe it shouldn't. Also provide env details, such as OS and Qt (not PyQt) versions.

Thank you so much, the suggestion you gave me fits with the results, the thing is that I was using a QPlaintTextEdit, it works the content from the QPlainTextEdit should be transferred to a QTextEdit, and then setting the size would disappear the number however, if we import long text, it will return to the same issue, but that was the result I had. modifying the MRE I Used

This is one of the reasons for which we need a proper MRE (and by "we" I also mean you). It's debugging fundamentals: you can't solve a problem until you're able to isolate it. I strongly suggest you to put more efforts in focusing about these aspects way before being distracted by others that may be irrelevant. For instance, you show lots of efforts in type hinting (which isn't bad), but then again your typing is inconsistent: self.text_edit is a QPlainTextEdit, not a QTextEdit. The fact that you didn't get that distinction shows that you should really focus on more important matters.

What exercises could you suggest me to focus in those aspects, I am very interesting in improve in my coding. Can we be in touch, interact with other coders can help me to improve as you made with me.

Sorry but no, I rarely get in touch privately (mostly because coding is not my primary profession and I have to focus on other matters). Still, I can suggest one thing: focus on what matters, and the priorities of what you're doing. Going back to the type hinting example: while typing can be important, it's also pointless if your code doesn't work. Good hinting doesn't make bad code good. Python doesn't really care about that, since it's dynamic typed, which means that: 1. that the logic of your code has to work first; 2. if you prioritize hinting over logic, you're wasting your resources.
